# How to update table with relationship to another table

Tags: c#, database

I have an Access database with 2 table NewSubject and NewStudentInfo and they also have a relationship. I want to Update the fields in NewSubject but it's not working. What to do? Thanks. See images below.

[Access Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnDxG.png)

2 different Codes for update but not working.

If I use this Code with Concatenate the MessageBox will popped-up and will say "Updated" but apparently it will not Update the Database. I will attach some images after the code for proof.

```
string conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Projects\Betches\MiniThesis\MACInfo\MACInfo\bin\Debug\Database\MasterList.accdb";
        string query = "UPDATE NewSubjects SET StudentID = '" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "',SubjectCode = '" + TextBoxSubjectCode.Text + "',SubjectDescription = '" + TextBoxSubjectDesc.Text + "',Unit = '" + TextBoxUnit.Text + "',SubjectGrade = '" + TextBoxSubjectGrade.Text + "',Course = '" + TextBoxCourse.Text + "',AcademicYear = '" + TextBoxYear.Text + "',Semester = '" + TextBoxSemester.Text + "' WHERE StudentID = '" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "';";
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(conn);
        OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
        OleDbDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            myReader = command1.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Updated!","MACInfo",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            Loader();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Note : I'm trying to update the first Row, Column 3 which is SubjectCode.
[Concat Code Image Proof CLICK ME!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0h3c.png)[CLICK ME FOR Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnORX.png)

If I'm going to use the Parameters.AddWithValue it will not update the database and it will show the messagebox saying "Update Unsuccessful!" but no error on code. An image is attached on footer for proof.

```
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=M1icrosoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Projects\Betches\MiniThesis\MACInfo\MACInfo\bin\Debug\Database\MasterList.accdb");
        command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = @"UPDATE NewSubjects SET [StudentID] = @Sid,
            [SubjectCode] = @Sc,
            [SubjectDescription] = @Sd,
            [Unit] = @Un,
            [SubjectGrade] = @Sg,
            [Course] = @Crs,
            [AcademicYear] = @Yr,
            [Semester] = @Sem WHERE [StudentID] = @Sid";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sid", maskedTextBox1.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SC", TextBoxSubjectCode.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sd", TextBoxSubjectDesc.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Un", TextBoxUnit.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sg", TextBoxSubjectGrade.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Crs", TextBoxCourse.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Yr", TextBoxYear.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sem", TextBoxSemester.Text);

        conn.Open();
        int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (rowsAffected != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Update Successful!", "MACInfo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            Loader();
            TextBoxSubjectCode.Enabled = false;
            TextBoxSubjectDesc.Enabled = false;
            TextBoxUnit.Enabled = false;
            TextBoxSubjectGrade.Enabled = false;
            TextBoxCourse.Enabled = false;
            TextBoxYear.Enabled = false;
            TextBoxSemester.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
        }
        conn.Close();
```

[Update Unsuccessful using Parameters.AddWithValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pff0k.png)

Comment: _I want to Update the fields in NewSubject but it's not working_ what is not working ? any error ?

Comment: " but not working" please describe in what way it is not working. If you are getting an error please include the complete text in the question. If you are just getting an unexpected result what is that result and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: **IMPORTANT** do not use string concatenation to build SQL: you're code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Always parameterise your SQL.

Comment: Okay sir wait I will update the post to add some new details

Comment: Edited. Please review

Comment: Side note: Nothing on any volunteer based community is ever urgent.

Comment: Unclear which image (and please include the exception type and message *as text* in the question) relate to which code sample

Comment: *Note* if `ExecuteNonQuery` returns 0 it means no rows match the condition in the update statement. This is not an error.